# Python Requests API requests.get() call with params is not working as intended (response ignores params)

Tags: python, web-scraping, get, python-requests, urllib3

Here is my code:

```js
import requests

find_doctors_url = 'http://www.americhoice.com/find_doctor/Ver2/results_doc.jsp'

payload ={"specialty":"ORSU","docproducts":"HOBD,HLOP","planNameDropDoc":"HOBD,HLOP","plan":"uhcwa","zip":"98122","zipradius":"10","findButton":"FIND DOCTOR","specialtyName":"ORTHOPAEDIC SURGERY"}

response = requests.get(find_doctors_url,params=payload)
print(response.url)
print(response.content)
```

when I print response.content, all I receive is:

```
<!-- NEAADR0179 -Anil Kumar Vutikuri *** End-->


<!--BEGIN SETTING HEADERS TO NO CACHE-->

<!--END SETTING HEADERS TO NO CACHE-->

<!--SET SESSION VALUES FROM URL PARAMETERS-->


<!--END SET SESSION VALUES FROM URL PARAMETERS-->
```

Which is the response you receive when you navigate to:
view-source:http://www.americhoice.com/find_doctor/Ver2/results_doc.jsp

However, I am seeking to return the complete html received when you navigate to the url generated by response.url

view-source:http://www.americhoice.com/find_doctor/Ver2/results_doc.jsp?specialty=ORSU&docproducts=HOBD%2CHLOP&planNameDropDoc=HOBD%2CHLOP&plan=uhcwa&zip=98122&zipradius=10&findButton=FIND+DOCTOR&specialtyName=ORTHOPAEDIC+SURGERY

The problems seems to be that the request is not sending the GET query params correctly

Things I have tried (unsuccessfully):
1)Requesting the complete URL(encoded) instead of using a params dictionary
2)Using the urllib3 library instead of the Requests library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the view-source website you give returns 404 error.

Second, what do you get when you print `response.url`? It should return full url including `params` concatenated.

Comment: Ah, before when I was in the same session it was coming up, now when I restarted my browser I get a blank screen (still 200 request). Must require some session data

Comment: @AmiyaDiwan So maybe you need to login or something else before you send a `GET` request? In this case, you should use `requests.session` to keep session during different requests.

Comment: Thanks @Sraw, that was the fix!